# Is it mandatory to install tomcat 7 to install klaros test management community edition even though there is tomcat installed and running

Tags: tomcat7

We are trying to install the [Klaros-Testmanagement](http://www.klaros-testmanagement.com) test case management tool (Community Edition). While installing, the [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) application container will be installed by the package automatically.

My doubt is even though there is tomcat running, why tomcat server needs to be installed again.

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 0):

Klaros-Testmanagement is supported and tested with the supplied Tomcat version only, which also contains some configuration changes from a vanilla Tomcat distribution.

The rationale behind this is to update the distribution on a regular basis and ensure that JVM memory settings and other parameters are configured properly.

If you are feeling adventurous you can try using another version of Tomcat or a completely other application server.

For this you may download the [.war only distribution](http://www.klaros-testmanagement.com/files/webapps/klaros-web.war) and install it in your container.

Make sure you are picking up configuration changes in the `conf` and `bin` folders by diffing them to a vanilla tomcat distribution.

You definitely have to:

- Raise memory limitations, esp. MaxPermSize when running under Java 7: `-XX:MaxPermSize=192m -Xms256m -Xmx768m` or more if needed/available.
- Disable session persistence: Uncomment `<Manager pathname=""/>` in `conf/context.xml`

Beware that other configuration changes may arise in future releases without further notice, so you are pretty much on your own if things stop working.